# How to disable finger service in Solaris 8

Tags: unix, solaris

I have a request from audit to remove finger service in Solaris 8 machine.

I try putting remark in /etc/inetd.conf and pkill -HUP it, but when i type finger it still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing `finger` on the local system will work even if the service is disabled. I believe it queries the utmp file directly. To test the service, however, try:

```
finger user@host
```

from another host (substituting an appropriate username and hostname, of course), or:

```
finger user@localhost
```

from the system you're testing. You should get a "connection refused" message.

By the way, it is good security practice to go ahead and disable ***all*** services that aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by typing finger? Can you see the service running? To type finger is not the way to test it :)

Comment: How to check if finger service is running? and how to test if its successfully stop by putting remark in /etc/inetd.conf file

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
netstat -an | grep $PORTNUMBER
```

to see if it is listening on that port.